# Weyl algebra as an Azumaya algebra over its centre

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, characteristic-p, positive-characteristic, weyl-algebra, azumaya-algebras

Assume that $k$ is an algebraically closed field of positive characteristic $p$. On page 3 (page 6 of the PDF file) of [Bezrukavnikov, Mirković, and Rumynin - Localisation of Modules for a semisimple Lie Algebra in prime characteristic](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0205144), we have the following sentence:

> The sheaf $D_X$ of crystalline differential operators on a smooth variety $X$ over $k$ has a non-trivial center, canonically identified with the sheaf of functions on the Frobenius twist $T^∗X^{(1)}$ of the cotangent bundle. Moreover $D_X$ is an Azumaya algebra over $T^∗X^{(1)}$.

Instead of going through the general proof given, I only want to understand, in as simple a manner as possible, the situation when $X$ is the affine $n$-space over $k$. In this case, $D_X$ is simply the Weyl algebra and the Azumaya property, if I understand correctly, means that the quotient of the Weyl algebra by its centre is isomorphic to some matrix algebra over $k$. Is there a way to construct such a matrix algebra and a corresponding isomorphism to the quotient explicitly? Any help, even in the case of the affine line, would be highly appreciated.

**P.S.** If my understanding is incorrect, could you please point out the flaw(s) and how the question could be turned into something reasonable?

**Major Edit** It has been pointed out that my understanding of the Azumaya property is incorrect. But my question remains the same: is there a direct way to prove the claim of the paper in the case when $X$ is the affine $n$-space (or even the affine line) over $k$.

Comment: Your definition of Azumaya algebra is incorrect — see [Azumaya algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azumaya_algebra).

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. Even if that is the case, will the quotient of the Weyl algebra by its centre be isomorphic to a matrix algebra?

Comment: The trivial Azumaya algebra (say, over a field) is a matrix algebra, so the quotient by its center is **not** a matrix algebra.

Comment: @abx If I consider $n=1$ and consider $k[x]/x^p$ and let $x$ and $\partial$ define the standard actions on $k[x]/x^p$. Then since the centre of the Weyl algebra is just $k[x^p, \partial^p]$, each element of the quotient will define an endomorphism of $k[x]/x^p$. Will/can this be an isomorphism?

Comment: [No](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368886/weyl-algebra-as-an-azumaya-algebra-over-its-centre#comment931042_368886).  Even briefer version of [my previous argument](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368886/weyl-algebra-as-an-azumaya-algebra-over-its-centre#comment931034_368886):  $k[x, \partial]/k[x^p, \partial^p]$, or even just $k[x, \partial]/k$, is Abelian, so can't be $\operatorname{End}_k(k[x]/(x^p))$.

Comment: @LSpice Thank you! Is there any simple way to prove the statement from the paper for the Weyl algebra?

Comment: @abx Do you have any ideas for an elementary proof of the statement in the case of the Weyl algebra?

Comment: @LSpice What if I quotient it by the ideal generated by $x^p$ and $\partial^p$? My hunch is that this *will* become a matrix algebra. Do you think this makes sense? If so, do you see any direct way of proving it?

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I do not know an elementary proof off the top of my head.  My initial comment, which I have now deleted, did not make much sense; it was basically about taking the quotient by the ideal, but I confused myself partway.  Anyway, if the quotient were a matrix algebra, it would have to be $\mathfrak{gl}_p$, with $X$ and $\partial$ as regular nilpotents with commutator $1$.  I think that this can be realised by $X$ the matrix with $1$s on the superdiagonal, $\partial$ the matrix with subdiagonal $1, 2, 3, \dotsc, p - 1$.

Comment: (More conceptually—and maybe that's what you wanted from [your comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368886/weyl-algebra-as-an-azumaya-algebra-over-its-centre#comment931042_368886)?—[this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368886/weyl-algebra-as-an-azumaya-algebra-over-its-centre#comment931060_368886) is the realisation of $k[x, \partial]/(x^p, \partial^p)$ as $\operatorname{End}_k(k[x]/(x^p))$ *via* the natural action.)

Comment: @LSpice I am very sorry, but could you please elaborate a bit more on that? I am having difficulty understanding exactly what you mean.

Comment: Hmm, I thought links to chat were added automatically, but it doesn't seem to be happening here.  We moved the discussion to a chat room:  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/111685/discussion-between-user11235813-and-lspice .

Comment: That was my fault! Very, very sorry! I initially opted to move it to the chat and then deleted the (automatic) comment because I thought that having a discussion here was better, only to change my mind again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But my question remains the same: is there a direct way to prove the
> claim of the paper in the case when  is the affine -space (or even
> the affine line) over .

Yes, read the proof of Proposition 1 in "[The Jacobian Conjecture is stably equivalent to the Dixmier Conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0512171)" by Alexei Belov-Kanel and Maxim Kontsevich.

If you are only interested in the $n=1$ case $A=k \langle X,Y \mathrel| XY-YX=1 \rangle$, then give $X$ degree $1$ and $Y$ degree $-1$, so that $A$ becomes a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded ring. It is even strongly graded, meaning $A_1\cdot A_{-1} = A_0$, so all graded info is determined by the zero-part $A_0=k[XY]$. In particular, if you divide out a graded maximal ideal you get a strongly graded ring with part of degree $0$ a field and finite over its center, and these must be central simple algebras (in this case, just $p \times p$ matrices) proving that $A$ is what is called a graded Azumaya algebra. Now, for the fun part, as there exist homogeneous central identities, a graded Azumaya algebra is a genuine Azumaya algebra. Done.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. Thank you so much for the reference and the explanation!